# Simplified Chinese Stroke order animation

Tags: characters, stroke-order

I want to show Simplified Chinese stroke order animation with unity or C#, is there an open source library?
If not, is there paid repository of stroke order diagrams in unity or C#?

Comment: There are strike order animations in zdict, like: http://www.zdic.net/z/1e/js/738B.htm . But I don't know if they sell the resource.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/skishore/makemeahanzi - it uses javascript btw

Comment: Wikimedia Commons has a [Stroke Order Project](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Stroke_Order_Project).

Comment: You need a stroke order database, not a .Net library. Try to search NuGet

Comment: Try asking it in the coding section of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the first result on google:
https://github.com/chanind/hanzi-writer